# Use Metadata field in formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

It seems that SharePoint didn't allow Managed Metadata columns to be used in calculated fields something like a decade ago.

Is there a way to add metadata field/column in a calculated column's formula today (end of 2022)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed metadata columns are not supported in calculated column formula.

Columns of the following data types can be referenced in a formula: single line of text, number, currency, date and time, choice, yes/no, and calculated.

Comment: why MS does not support? Just let adding [metadata].ToString() the minimum needed. Is it so complicated?

Comment: Not sure, you might want to [raise support ticket directly with Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support) or [submit new feedback/idea](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) for this feature support.

Comment: Hi @serge, does this answer your question?

Comment: it answers que question, however, I don't like the answer :D

Comment: Unfortunately, the limitation of SharePoint. Managed Metadata are one of complex fields.